# Distance between two functions satisfying a constraint

Tags: differential-equations, mathematical-optimization

My problem is that I have two functions that are described as follows:

```
x1 = 
  x[t] /. DSolve[{55 x''[t] + 100*n x'[t] + (5/22)*n x[t] == 5, x'[0] == 1/8, x[0] == 0}, 
    x[t], t][[1]]
x2 = 
  x[t] /. DSolve[{x''[t] + 1 == 0, x'[0] == 1/8, x[0] == 0}, x[t], t][[1]]
```

Variable `n` in function `x1` ranges from 1 to 8. I want to find which `n` enables `x1` to come as close to `x2` as possible without falling below `x2`. Or stated otherwise, what is the highest `n` that ensures `x1 > x2` at all times.

A plot of the functions reveals that most of the action takes place between `t = 0` and `t = 0.15`. However, the curves are too close to each other to read the right `n` from my screen. I have been trying ways to calculate the difference with integration, solving and all types of manners for hours now, but I'm certain there must be an easier way to achieve this within *Mathematica*.

Comment: When you say $x1$ to come close to $x2$ you mean for one point $t$ or in average?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an `n` that "ensures `x1 > x2` at all times", I think it may not be possible. Look at the plot below, it seems for `t` negative enough, `x1` will eventually below `x2` for all $1 \leq n \leq 8$:

```
Plot3D[
 Evaluate[x1 - x2], {t, -4, 1}, {n, 1, 8},
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #2 &}, Mesh -> {{0}, 20},
 MeshStyle -> {Directive[Red, Thick], Gray},
 BoundaryStyle -> Thick,
 ClippingStyle -> {Lighter[Blue, .7], Directive[{Lighter[Green, .5]}]},
 PlotRange -> {0, .1}, Lighting -> "Neutral",
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 20, Lighter[Blue], Bold] & /@ {t, n, "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(1\)]\)-\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)]\)"})]
```

[image: plot]

## Edit

In case OP wants ask for additional constraint $0\leq t$, we can see from the plot below that the highest $n$ happens at the cross point indicated with purple crayon:

[image]

However, simply   substituting $t=0$ into equation $x_1-x_2=0$ will not work, since `x1 - x2 /. t -> 0` is always `0`.

In order to help understanding what happened near the cross point, we can plot it out:

[image]

So the cross point we are interested in, that is, the $n$ we are looking for, makes the curvature of the curve $z = f(t) = x_1-x_2$ vanishing at $t=0$.

```
Function[{x, f}, D[f, {x, 2}]/(1 + D[f, x]^2)^(3/2)][t, x1 - x2] /. t -> 0 // FullSimplify
```

> $$\frac{1}{22} (24-5 n)$$

So the highest $n$ that ensures $x_1 \geq x_2$ on $0\leq t$ near $0$ is $\frac{24}{5}=4.8$.

---

Another possible approach would be expanding $x_1-x_2$ near $t=0$

```
Series[x1 - x2, {t, 0, 3}]
```

> $$\left(\frac{6}{11}-\frac{5 n}{44}\right) t^2+\left(\frac{25 n^2}{363}-\frac{107 n}{3872}\right) t^3+O\left(t^4\right)$$

and forcing the coefficients of terms with order $\leq 2$ vanishing, which gives the same answer $\frac{24}{5}$.

---

For verification, here we plot the line of equation $x_1-x_2=0$

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate[x1 - x2 == 0], {t, 0, 10^-4}, {n, 4.7995, 4.801},
 PlotPoints -> 200,
 ContourStyle -> Lighter[Blue, .6],
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 20, Bold] & /@ {t, n}),
 GridLines -> {None, {24/5}},
 GridLinesStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

Comment: He wants between $0<t<0.15$

Comment: @Spawn1701D I take that words of OP means the interval he considered in order to solve the problem, not the domain/constraint on t in the problem itself.

Comment: @Alex I'm not sure I catch up with you. Is `x1-x2/.{ n-> .. , t -> .. }` not enough? For the time domain, try `FindRoot[x1 - x2 /. n -> #, {t, .1}] &[(*your n value greater than 24/5*)]`.

Comment: @Alex Thanks for acceptance. Please see my edit.